# Multi-dimensional Dictionary in VBScript always gets last values?

Tags: dictionary, multidimensional-array, vbscript

I'm basically trying to create a multi-dimensional associative array in vbscript using a dictionary with sub-dictionaries as the items for each key.

Effectively:

```
myAssocArray = 
    "app1" =
        "appid" => "1"
        "name"  => "alpha"
    "app2" =
        "appid" => "2"
        "name"  => "beta"
```

This is my code. It loops through each dictionary fine, but when it gets to the subdictionary, it ALWAYS echos out the values of the "last" element. So when echoing "app1" it will show appid of "2" and name of "beta" but it should show "1" and "alpha" respectively.

```
Dim dict
Dim dict2

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Create a dictionary to be used as the "items" value for the main dictionary
dict2.Add "appid", "1"
dict2.Add "name", "alpha"

' Add it to the main dictionary as the item with Key of "1"
dict.Add "app1", dict2

' Clear the temp second dictionary
dict2.RemoveAll

' Add a new dictionary dimension for the second item
dict2.Add "appid", "2"
dict2.Add "name", "beta"
dict.Add "app2", dict2

' Loop through the main dictionary, and go through each item (sub-dictionary)
For Each key In dict.Keys
    MsgBox key
    For Each key2 In dict.Item(key).Keys
        MsgBox dict.Item(key).Item(key2)
    Next
Next
```

This prints out

```
app1 = 
    "appid" = "2"
    "name"  = "beta"
app2 =
    "appid" = "2"
    "name"  = "beta"
```

Completely skipping over the first item's values. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.Add "app1", dict2`

This adds a *reference* to `dict2` not a copy so any subsequent changes to `dict2` will be reflected in the `"app1"` item.

(At the end of your script `"app1"`, `"app2"` and `dict2` are all the same Dictionary)

Rather than `RemoveAll` you need a new Dictionary so repeat `Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`

Comment: Also, on windows if you can use VBScript you can also use JScript in the scripting host which obviously makes associative arrays very simple.

Comment: Thanks Alex... also great point about the Jscript.. I didn't even think about using that. That would make life MUCH simpler.

Comment: You can also create the nested dictionary directly in the `Add` statement: `dict.Add "app1", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`, and then add the nested key/value pairs like this: `dict("app1").Add "appid", "2"`.

Answer (score 1):

A complete script set

```
set dict=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'add items
dict.Add "app1", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
with dict("app1") 
  .Add "appid", "2"
  .Add "val", "pepe"
end with 

dict.Add "app2", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
with dict("app2") 
  .Add "appid", "4"
  .Add "val", "maria"
end with 

'traverse 
For Each i In dict.keys  
  wscript.echo i
  with dict(i)
    For Each j In .keys 
       wscript.echo vbtab & j & vbtab & .item(j)
    Next 
  end with
next
```

Comment: Thanks - this nested dictionary approach helped me this weekend.