# How can i store ADODB.Recordset in a variable NOT by reference?

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following code

```
Dim rs,SQL
Dim svrs, prods
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
rs.Open SQL,conn // conn is the connection variable

svrs = Array(rs("server_name"))
prods = Array(rs("product_name"))
rs.MoveNext

For Each item In svrs
    Response.Write item
    Response.Write "<br>"
Next
Response.Write "<br>"

For Each item In prods
    Response.Write item
    Response.Write "<br>"
Next
Response.Write "<br>"
```

and the schema of `myTable is`

```
server_name | product_name
--------------------------
svr1        | prod 1
server2     | prod 2
server2     | prod 3
```

---

now the expected result on the webpage should be showing `svr1` and `prod 1` but instead i get `server2` and `prod 2`. this to me suggest that `rs()` is sending the reference to the `rs` variables and as such, when i go `rs.MoveNext` since my array[0] is just a reference to `rs()` they values change aswell which isn't good for populating these arrays

What i want to know is how can i store ADODB.Recordset so it's not passed by reference

---

NOTE: i should point out that the above code is only a sample of the full code. in between the `MoveNext` and `For Each` i then go though the results using loops to populate the `svrs` and `prods` arrays with only unique values by using `ReDim Preserve` to expand them dynamically.

the original code when doing the `For Each` gave an error about the record set was either deleted or at the end and the above code from the debugging revealed that the first value wasn't even correct.

---

this for those who [insist you needed more context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534953/how-can-i-store-adodb-recordset-in-a-variable-not-by-reference?noredirect=1#comment84130939_48534953).

the original code was

```
Dim rs,SQL
Dim svrs, prods, vers
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set vers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
rs.Open SQL,conn 

svrs = Array(rs("server_name"))
prods = Array(rs("product_name"))
vers.Add rs("server_name")&"-"&rs("product_name"),rs("version")
rs.MoveNext

Do While NOT rs.EoF
    If inArray(svrs,rs("server_name")) = false Then
        ReDim Preserve svrs(UBound(svrs) + 1)
        svrs(UBbound(svrs)) = rs("sever_name")
    End If
    
    If inArray(prods,rs("server_name")) = false Then
        ReDim Preserve prods(UBound(prods) + 1)
        prods(UBbound(prods)) = rs("sever_name")
    End If
    
    vers.Add rs("server_name")&"-"&rs("product_name"),rs("version")
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

For Each item In svrs
    Response.Write item
    Response.Write "<br>"
Next
Response.Write "<br>"

For Each item In prods
    Response.Write item
    Response.Write "<br>"
Next
Response.Write "<br>"
```

with the schema of `myTable is`

```
key | server_name   | product_name  | version
---------------------------------------------
1   | svr1          | prod 1        | 1.0.2
2   | server2       | prod 2        | 1.0.1
3   | server2       | prod 3        | 1.0.14
```

NOTE: yes i am using a server and product table and am using foreign key here in the final version and yes key is a primary key

the idea was to display the data like

```
        | server    | server    | server    |
---------------------------------------------
product | version   | version   | version   |
product | version   | version   | version   |
product | version   | version   | version   |
product | version   | version   | version   |
product | version   | version   | version   |
```

now because i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26219754/1028804) that putting a dictionary in a dictionary would only put in a reference i couldn't create an empty `prods` dictionary as like a template for populating with versions (with missing versions being empty) so i decided to create 2 arrays **of unique `svrs` and `prods` values** to then use as the basis of loops for accessing a composite dictionary key for the versions.

because (at the time) i didn't know how to initialize an empty array that wouldn't error on the `inArray` i decided to create the array with the first server and product values and then loop though appending them.

after all of this was done i wanted to make sure i got unique values for `svrs` and `prods` so i did the loops to output them. the error i got was

> ADODB.Field error '80020009'
>
> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record had been deleted. Requested Operation requires a current record
>
> /myFile.asp, line 0

to test to make sure it wasn't my `Do While` loop i removed the outputting loops and i didn't get the error so i removed the `Do While` loop and put back in the outputting loops suspecting that if **my arrays which are supposed to have the first element was actually holding the referees to `rs` and thus explaining the ADODB error i got, i would then not see the first values from the table but the second**

and because i can not log into SO from the developer machine i have where in the workplace or plug in a USB device to copy the code i had to rewrite it so i wrote it as **Minimal Verifiable Code** on another machine which i then tested and got the same incorrect results from what i was expecting. the removal of the `Do While` and the change of the table was to remove irrelevant factors (ie. i as stated i got the same incorrect results with the rewritten cut down code)

Comment: Can I respectfully request that when you post cutdown code you give it a bit more context? Some of us spent time helping you out with general technique because what you posted was so full of inconsistencies. That said, using for - next to fill an array that you then process in a further loop is definitely sub-optimal for performance. If you have to load an array us GetRows().

Comment: @VanquishedWombat i don't see why I needed to. I have posted minimum verifiable code of my problem that despite creating an array which was supposed to be filled with just the first element from record set the following loops were showing the second. if I had posted the full code (which I debugged to this point) and you tried to run it you would get an error which would prevent any results from appearing. however if it's that much of a problem you'll need to wait for me to write it all because my work environment prevents me from logging into SO on the developer machine or using a USB

Comment: @VanquishedWombat i have edited the question with the context you wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is use the field's [value property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/value-property-ado) instead of the field itself.

```vb
svrs = Array(rs("server_name").Value)
prods = Array(rs("product_name").Value)
```

Comment: unless you only have one record being returned from the database, this answer is incorrect. Also, the only time you need to specify the difference between rs("fldName") and rs("fldName").Value is when you're using JScript as your server side language. VBScript will explicitly translate a reference to a rs field to it's value.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery No, it's not a JScript thing directly. With `rs("fldName")` you have a Field object with a defaut property that returns the value which VBScript can use it implicitly. When you assign this field object to an array (doesn' matter JScript or VBScript), an object reference will be copied instead of the value. That's the problem OP's looking for a solution here. You can see the main difference with by checking `Response.Write TypeName(rs("fldName"))` and `Response.Write TypeName(rs("fldName").Value)`. So, this answer is totally correct as OP is aware of it.

Comment: So if you have 10 rows returned, and the data you're looking for is in the 3rd row, your code will work w/out a loop? If so, I would love to see how this works. Yes, you are technically storing a reference to the recordset field, but vbscript is smart enough to translate that to the recordset fields VALUE, JScript will not do this.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery It's a problem you imagined I think, there's no something like  stated in the question. Naturally I do not intend to answer a question that was not asked by the OP. Apparently he/she knows how to populate an array. See the OP's edit.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not explicitly setting the size of the arrays, you need to preserve any previous data in the array BEFORE adding a new record to the data. You can do this by using REDIM PRESERVE:

```vbs
Dim rs,SQL, counter : counter = 0
Dim svrs()
Dim prods()
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
'-- since you're only grabbing data from the DB, you don't need to worry about managing cursors, meaning it's more efficient to use set rs = conn.Execute( sql )
set rs = conn.Execute( sql )

do while not rs.EOF
    Redim Preserve svrs( counter )
    Redim Preserve prods( counter )

    svrs( counter )  = rs("server_name")
    prods( counter ) = rs("product_name")
    rs.MoveNext
loop

For Each item In svrs
    Response.Write item
    Response.Write "<br>"
Next
Response.Write "<br>"

For Each item In prods
    Response.Write item
    Response.Write "<br>"
Next
Response.Write "<br>"
```

With all that said, is there a particular reason you have 2 separate arrays instead of just a 2D array? If you only need one array, it would be a lot easier just to use [GetRows](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_getrows.asp) to transfer your recordset data into an array:

```
set rs = conn.Execute( sql )
dim arr2D = rs.GetRows()
```

now, you have all of your data in an array and no longer need 2 different arrays and can skip the Do-While loop.